# LaTeX on top of a pdf

Tags: graphics, pdf, forms

Suppose we have a pdf file of a form that of A4 format.

Without saying so, the writer of the pdf form expects us to print it out, fill in the form by hand and post it as a snail mail.

Is it possible to import the pdf into a LaTeX document (similar to import of an image file) and fill in the form using say a large `tabular` environment.

Comment: I would include the pdf with Ti*k*z using the options `overlay` and `remember picture` and then fill out the form using `tabular`. The vertical and horizontal spacing need to be adjusted manually though.

Comment: I use following \includegraphics[page=1,width=1.2\textwidth]{filename.pdf} it works, say, for the first page of your pdf-document